# Windows 7: logging system and user preferences changes to apply them later on another system

Tags: windows, registry, settings, diff, preferences

I'm setting up system and user preferences on newly installed Windows 7 system. I.e. I'm walking through all Control Panel applets and changing some options, setting up Explorer, Firewall preferences and so on. I'm adjusting power plans. I'm doing TaskBar and Start Menu customization, etc. I want to record all these changes to apply them later on another computer (with different hardware) automatically. How to do it?

Thanks!

I ask more narrowly: how to record all registry changes made while changing system settings in Control Panel (e.g. power plans, opting out from user experience program, etc.) and then apply such registry diff to another system (the same OS, but different hardware and OS bitness might be another)?

I know there are tools exist to monitor registry, but please share a real experience acoording to the task I specified above. There are some obstacles, e.g. some system items, e.g. power schemes have unical GUIDs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Windows Easy Transfer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff943667.aspx), which is supported on Windows 7. The linked article says that it was originally created to help users upgrade from XP, but the tool also allows you to "upgrade" from one Windows 7 machine to another.

Comment: This tool does not transfer system preferences, i.e. power plans, disabling Windows Defender, etc.